# Duplicate Management Rule

Tags: duplicate-management

I have Created a Duplicate Rule when inserting a new Contact, Contact Email find same Email value which is already existing Contact Email it should throw an error. I did it with Duplicate Management. It is working Fine but I need to Prevent Duplicate error for some User . I need that 2 or 3 user should not get this error when they are inserting duplicate records. Is this possible through Duplicate Management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the duplicate rule you can add criteria for the rule to run, you can use this to filter out and bypass certain conditions. For example the screenshot below would not run if the current user had the "SomeProfile" Profile or lastName of "SomeName":

[image]

Personally I would not use name - this requires maintenance and user's join and leave. You could use a custom field on the User record as well (e.g. a checkbox that allows bypass).